# embedded linux with busybox auto-login

Tags: embedded-linux, autologin, busybox

I need to make a QT app to run on the startup of an embedded linux system that I made. I have access to the system via serial port ttySAC0. I tried adding the app to inittab , it runs but tslib is not working, probably because it can't find the environment variables it needs to work because I'm setting those environment variables in the /etc/.profile file which runs after user login. I need to auto login a user so the environment variables are set so tslib would work, or a way to set those environment variables without logging in. The system is made with buildroot and busybox.

Comment: Hi @iah.vector, you can write a script under /etc/init.d/S99_your_script. The environment variables can be set up inside this script, then you can invoke your Qt application in background mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out, I made this shell script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#Sets necessary environment variables and runs the desktop
#

export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/touchscreen-1wire
export TSLIB_TSEVENTTYPE=INPUT
export TSLIB_FBDEVICE=/dev/fb0
export TSLIB_PLUGINDIR=/usr/lib/ts/
export TSLIB_CONSOLEDEVICE=none
export TSLIB_CONFFILE=/etc/ts.conf
export TSLIB_CALIBFILE=/etc/pointercal
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib
export QTDIR=/usr/lib/qt
export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=tslib:/dev/touchscreen-1wire

/path/to/application -qws
```

Then made it executable with:

```
$chmod +x startup.sh
```

then added this line to inittab:

```
tty1::once:/path/to/startup.sh
```

Now when I boot up, the application is running fine with tslib and I still got acces via serial line whenever I need.

Answer (score 1):

Write a `/etc/init.d/S99myapp` script that starts your application after having executed the necessary `export VARIABLE=value` commands to define all environment variables you need. You can look for example at `package/stunnel/S50stunnel` in the Buildroot sources for an example of initscript.

Comment: I wrote an rc script named S99exportEnvVars containing this:
#!/bin/sh
#
# Export Environmentvariables for QT and TSLib
#

case "$1" in
start)
echo "Exporting TSLib environment variables..."
export TSLIB_TSDEVICE=/dev/touchscreen-1wire
echo "Exporting QT environment variables..."
export QTDIR=/usr/lib/qt
export QWS_MOUSE_PROTO=tslib:/dev/touchscreen-1wire
;;
stop)
;;
restart|reload)
;;
*)
echo "invalid!"
exit 1
esac
exit $?

When I rebooted, I got the echoed lines which means the script is working, but when I logged in I found that non of the env vars is set.

Comment: That's because your exports are terminal dependent. They don't remain as when you put them in your `.bashrc` file.